# I want to implement a doubly circular linked list - runtime error in my code

Tags: c++, data-structures

Here is what i have tried.  I get a runtime error :| ....to be precise, I figure there is something wrong with my push function, but i can't seem to figure it out !!

```
    class dcll
    {
    struct node
    {
       T data;
      node *next; node* prev;
       node(){}
       node(T data,node* n,node *p)
     {
        this->data=data; next=n; prev=p;
     }
   };
    node *head;  
    public:
    dcll(){head=NULL;}
    void push( T val)
    {
          if(!head) //initial situation
      head=new node(val,head,head);
          else //successive insertions
   {
      node *new_node=head; 
     while(new_node->next!=head)
     new_node=new_node->next;
     new_node->next=new node(val,head,new_node);
     head->prev=new_node->next;
   } 
    }

    };
```

Comment: Linked lists always require extensive debugging.  Even when you think you have them right you find "edge conditions" that break.  A doubly linked list requires twice as much debugging.

Comment: Apropos the above, I suggest it's time to write to some unit tests.  In fact, a *lot* of unit tests.

Comment: How do you *know* something is wrong?  What input did you give your program? What result did you expect, and how does that differ from what you actually got?

Comment: *"I get a runtime error"* - what error? Please be specific. Specific doesn't mean *"there is something wrong with my push function"* - it means, *"When I provide my program with input X, I expect output Y, but instead I get output Z"*.

Comment: Where one guesses the problem is is not always where the problem is. It would help to give us an [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example)](http://sscce.org) that reproduces whatever problem you are seeing (although debugging your program to find the problem yourself is generally preferred).

Comment: "runtime error" - you can solve this by running the program under the debugger, which will also show you where the error occurs.

Comment: @JBentley i shall keep that in mind !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that during the initialization of your head node, you pass the pointer to the head node as a parameter. However, this pointer is still NULL at that point in time, as it only gets the address of the new object, after the object was created.

A possible solution would be:

```
void push( T val)
{
    if(!head) //initial situation
        head=new node(val,head,head);
        head->next=head;
        head->prev=head;
    else //successive insertions
    {
      ...
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain the error you are getting?

also why are you doing something like this

```
while(new_node->next!=head)
    new_node=new_node->next;
```

Why Don't you do something like

- get hold of head say H
- get head's previous say HP
- create your new node say N with N's previous = HP and N's next = H
- now set H's previous to N
- and HP's next to N.

I have not tried this but, I think this will be safe.

Comment: I think MikeMB pointed the error you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bugs here, but the first one I see has to do with the initialization of the first element in `push()`:

```
if(!head) //initial situation
    head=new node(val,head,head);
```

Since head is `NULL`, the new node's `next` and `prev` pointers are also going to be `NULL`.

This causes the runtime error you're seeing when you try to call `push()`. Specifically, this loop won't work:

```
node *new_node=head; 
while(new_node->next!=head)
    new_node=new_node->next;
```

`new_node` is initially a valid pointer, but `new_node->next` is NULL, so on the second iteration, your code tries to dereference a NULL pointer and subsequently crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Going to throw you a bone here and provide you with a working refactor of the code you've implemented so far, it might give you a way to better wrap your head around what you're doing. I'm also going to take a next step in adding a "tail" pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class DCLL
{
    // internal representation of a Node
    struct Node
    {
        T        m_value;
        Node*    m_next;
        Node*    m_prev;

        inline Node(T value, Node* prev, Node* next)
        {
            m_value = value;
            m_prev = prev;
            m_next = next;
            if (m_prev)
                m_prev->m_next = this;
            if (m_next)
                m_next->m_prev = this;
        }
    };

    Node* m_head;
    Node* m_tail;

public:
    DCLL() : m_head(nullptr), m_tail(nullptr) {}

    void push_front(T val)
    {
        m_head = new Node(val, nullptr, m_head);
        if (!m_tail)
            m_tail = m_head;
    }

    void push_back(T val)
    {
        m_tail = new Node(val, m_tail, nullptr);
        if (!m_head)
            m_head = m_tail;
    }

    void walk() const
    {
        for (Node* node = m_head; node != nullptr; node = node->m_next) {
            std::cout << node->m_value << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    DCLL<int> ints;
    ints.push_front(3);
    ints.push_front(2);
    ints.push_front(1);
    ints.push_back(4);
    ints.push_back(5);
    ints.push_back(6);

    ints.walk();

    return 0;
}
```

You can see the demo here: http://ideone.com/nwlrbi